# http.get("https://poe.ninja/data") returning "https://poe.ninja" rather than the desired path of the domain

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a get request to "https://poe.ninja/data" but its not working how I thought it would and not sure how to get to that page specifically.

I'm relatively new to go and programming as a whole so if I'm missing anything obvious or completely off the track on how http.get works for this please let me know.

I've tried :
The homepage and that seems to be working as I thought. https://poe.ninja/
https://xkcd.com and https://xkcd.com/100
This works as I'd thought too getting the homepage and the 100 comic respectively

```golang
    resp, err := http.Get("https://poe.ninja/data/")
    if err != nil {panic(err)}
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}

    fmt.Println(string(body))

//From said code I'd expect to get the /data path but instead only get the homepage
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the homepage? The /data/ page appears to be generated by javascript.

Comment: The page returned from the Go program, a web browser and curl pretty much look the same.  Please describe what you expect and what you are getting.

Comment: @bserdar that might be in part my misunderstanding here but I thought the http.get response would be the same as the source of the page. Also the .../ request returns the same as .../data request, and they both the same to the source code I can see of the homepage

Comment: You did not misunderstand, and it is returning the source of the page. The difference is that after your get command, there is nothing to run the javascript returned to build the page. The page is dynamically generated by Javascript.

Comment: The page returned to the browser and the Go program are identical, byte for byte.  See `view-source:https://poe.ninja/data`

Comment: @CeriseLimón I was expecting to get the source code for the "https://poe.ninja/data" but its returning the html source code of the "https://poe.ninja" instead.

Comment: @bserdar I think I understand, is there anyway to get the html source of the data page as if I was visiting it on a web browser

Comment: There is no easy way to do that. You need to run the javascript.

Comment: @bserdar fair enough, ill look for an alternative way of doing it, thanks

Comment: Try using something like: https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp

Answer (score 0):

React, Vue and other front-end frameworks use client-side routing (JavaScript path detection) to render content into the browser. This prevents the need for the client to contact the web server on every click and navigation. This could mean one of two things:

- The client will make an API call to the server to fetch the data. Use something like Developer Tools' Network tab to keep dibs on what endpoints the client it communicating with
- Using a headless Chrome/WebKit, etc approach with JavaScript enabled. This will allow your tool to pull down the page contents, render using JavaScript, and ultimately return the computed front-end code. Due to the way that clients render single page apps, it may be difficult following specific `div#id` and `div#class` elements